# Cookie based auth Logout not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I am building a cookie based session mechanism which has an abstract class Session which can be extended to make multiple cookie session instances for varying use and complexity….

I also have an Auth class which handles permissions and the actual logging in and out of the user. The Auth class requires a Session Class or child class of to run.

Everything so far is great I can log a user in and also log them out if a certain amount of time has elapsed, ip address are not matching etc.

Every page load reads the cookie checks for inconsistencies and destroys or updates it depending on xyz. The destroy scripts set the time on the cookie back to minus now and remove any user data that has been added from the auth library. This works as I have logged in waited a few minutes then hit refresh and the cookie gets frazzled and I get bounced back to the login screen.

However If I want to log them out via them clicking a button the destroy scripts do not work i.e. I can echo the original user data at the top the run the log out script which echoes logging out and runs all the functions with no errors etc  but then If I get the users cookie it is still the same. I fail to understand how this can work for the automated checks but not when a user hits the logout button…

Below is my sessionDestroy function

```
protected function sessionDestroy($cookieName) {

    setcookie(
                $cookieName,
                addslashes(serialize(array())),
                (time() - 3600),
                0
        );          
}
```

P.S  I know destroy is a bad word for cookies but you know what I mean…… Hopefully

Answer (score -2):

why don't you use the cookie & session library built into CI?

the nice part about the session library, its using cookies which are encrypted. you find it to be a much better solution than what your doing.

Comment: -1 for suggesting another "complete solution". He wants to have custom session management.

Comment: he still can with the ci library, it'll just be less 'junk' he has to babysit. KISS is your friend.

Comment: He is asking why his solution is not working. Suggesting to abandon it for something else is not a viable answer.

Comment: I'm trying to educate him, if a framework provides a helper to make the job easier he should be using it, it'll most likely solved his problem.